# VBA Array of variant type as class property

Tags: arrays, vba, properties, variant

I have a class that handles several numeric arrays (type double) and also needs to handle an array of descriptors, which will include a mix of strings and integers, which need to be utilized as strings and numbers accordingly. So I decide to make an array property of type variant (not a variant containing an array). But this one does not seem to work, while the type double arrays do.

Specifically, this type double array-property works fine, to receive or return an array all at once:

```
Private p_dbNumericArray() As Double

Public Property Let NumericArray(Value() As Double)
    p_dbNumericArray() = Value()
End Property
Public Property Get NumericArray() As Double()
    NumericArray() = p_dbNumericArray()
End Property
```

But when I try the same pattern with an array of type variant, the Get property returns an empty/unallocated variant array:

```
Private p_vaVariantArray() As Variant

Public Property Let VariantArray(Value() As Variant)
    p_vaVariantArray() = Value()
End Property
Public Property Get VariantArray() As Variant()
    VariantArray() = p_vaVariantArray()
End Property
```

Wrapping an array in a variant (instead of having an array of type variant), of course works fine:

```
Private p_vaVariantArray As Variant

Public Property Let VariantArray(Value As Variant)
    p_vaVariantArray = Value
End Property
Public Property Get VariantArray() As Variant
    VariantArray = p_vaVariantArray
End Property
```

But is it known and standard that the pattern that works for Dim D() As Double does not work for Dim V() As Variant, in properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Property Get VariantArray() As Variant()
    VariantArray = p_vaVariantArray()
End Property
```

Note the missing parentheses.

Comment: Gah--another easy one! Thanks. What about the analogous line for the Double array " NumericArray( ) = p_dbNumericArray( )
 ", which seems to work fine with the extra parens? Are they optional here? Or is something subtle going on? Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops. Looks like that "NumericArray( ) = ..." actually doesn't work. I lost track of editing too many things at the same time. So those parentheses are just absolutely wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: @Romnie: Yes, the parens are always absolutely wrong. They are calling the function, but you actually want to assign to it (i.e. set the return value).