# Extracting a Specific Variable from a Class Module in VBA to a Standard Module

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, bloomberg

All,
The following code is from Bloomberg.  It is designed to extract bulk data from their servers.  The code works, but I am trying to extract a specific variable generated in the class module and bring it to the Regular Module for user defined functions.  Thanks for the help.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents session As blpapicomLib2.session
Dim refdataservice As blpapicomLib2.Service

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set session = New blpapicomLib2.session
session.QueueEvents = True
session.Start
session.OpenService ("//blp/refdata")
Set refdataservice = session.GetService("//blp/refdata")
End Sub

Public Sub MakeRequest(sSecList As String)
Dim sFldList As Variant
Dim req As Request
Dim nRow As Long
sFldList = "CALL_SCHEDULE"
Set req = refdataservice.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest") 'request type
req.GetElement("securities").AppendValue (sSecList) 'security + field as string array
req.GetElement("fields").AppendValue (sFldList) 'field as string var
Dim cid As blpapicomLib2.CorrelationId
Set cid = session.SendRequest(req)
End Sub

Public Sub session_ProcessEvent(ByVal obj As Object)
Dim eventObj As blpapicomLib2.Event
Set eventObj = obj
If Application.Ready Then
    If eventObj.EventType = PARTIAL_RESPONSE Or eventObj.EventType = RESPONSE Then
        Dim it As blpapicomLib2.MessageIterator
        Set it = eventObj.CreateMessageIterator()
        Do While it.Next()
            Dim msg As Message
            Set msg = it.Message
                Dim Security As Element
                Set Security = msg.GetElement("securityData").GetValue(0)
                Sheet1.Cells(4, 4).Value = Security.GetElement("security").Value
                Dim fieldArray As Element
                Set fieldArray = Security.GetElement("fieldData")
                    Dim field As blpapicomLib2.Element
                    Set field = fieldArray.GetElement(0)
                    If field.DataType = 15 Then
                        Dim numBulkValues As Long
                        numBulkValues = field.NumValues '76
                        Dim index As Long
                        For index = 0 To numBulkValues - 1
                            Dim bulkElement As blpapicomLib2.Element
                            Set bulkElement = field.GetValue(index)
                            Dim numBulkElements As Integer
                            numBulkElements = bulkElement.NumElements '2 elements per each pt
                            ReDim Call_Sch(0 To numBulkValues - 1, 0 To numBulkElements - 1) As Variant
                            Dim ind2 As Long
                            For ind2 = 0 To numBulkElements - 1
                                Dim elem As blpapicomLib2.Element
                                Set elem = bulkElement.GetElement(ind2)
                                Call_Sch(index,ind2)=elem.Value
                                Sheet1.Cells(index + 4, ind2 + 5) = elem.Value
                            Next ind2
                        Next index
                    Else
                    Call_Sch(index,ind2)=field.Value    
                    Sheet1.Cells(index + 4, ind2 + 5).Value = field.Value
                    End If
        Loop
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The variable i am trying to get, specifically, is the Call_Sch.  I want a function in the main module to recognize the variable.  Thanks again.

Comment: To make a value in a class visible externally, you make it a property, as in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342666/vba-array-of-variant-type-as-class-property Or you can just make your array public. But it appears you have not posted all of your code as there is no code that declare `Call_Sch` anywhere - only ReDim's it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to declare a variable before using ReDim on it; ReDim can declare a variable.  However, if you added:

```
Public Call_Sch() as Variant ' Insert correct data type here
```

then you would be able to refer to it via:

```
<YourClassVaraibleName>.Call_Sch
```